# Which are the correct pins for this footprint?

Tags: footprint

I'm creating a footprint for M140T01-AE0507A micro switch. [The datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1685047.pdf?_ga=2.19121400.1345300065.1496317608-494937798.1481711472) does not mention which symbol pins correspond to the device pins. I guess pin 1 is COM, but I don't know what the other two represent.

**Can someone help me out?**

Comment: From the schematic I'd guess that 3 (the middle one) is NO and 2 (the right one) is NC, but you are right the datasheet is not exactly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the following: -

[image]

But I would also want to check one with a meter just in case.